# Atom editor : Bookmark package: bookmark toggle not working with default key mapping

Tags: atom-editor

- I use Atom 1.8.0 on Windows 7.
- The keymapping says, 'ctrl-alt-f2' with selector '.platform-win32 atom-text-editor'. If I press the combination of buttons, nothing happens.
- I mapped the bookmark toggle operation to another key mapping ('ctrl-shift-1') just to see if it works, and it works. My problem of bookmarking is solved, but I wanted to know why the default combination is not working.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I trouble shoot this to find the root cause ?

Comment: Do you have to press additional keys to access the function keys, e.g. the `Fn` key?

Comment: @idleberg Nope. Direct keys F1,F2....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [keybinding-resolver](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) is a great way to detect conflicting keyboard shortcuts. If there are conflicts, you can use `unset!` to disable existing shortcuts.

If the problem persists, make sure the same shortcut isn't used globally. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3930) reporting the Intel Graphics Control Panel is using the same shortcut globally.

Comment: I manualy checked for the conflict. I did not find any conflicts with the default key mapping. Besides, the 'ctrl + F2', which shows the list of bookmarks works correctly.

Comment: Thank you. This is solved now. Intel Graphics Control Panel is using the same key combination as you said. I had disabled it from its control panel.